# Failing to move a listView with css

Tags: asp.net, css, listview

I am trying to move a list view with css...It moves to the left when i give it some value in the div tag in the layout template..but when I run it in the browser what I get is a listView sitting in the same place.. here is the code with the two problematic listviews:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/CP.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
     CodeFile="Spam.aspx.cs" Inherits="Moderator_Spam" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
     <br />
     <asp:Label ID="CommentHeader" runat="server" Text="הודעות ספאם של פוסטים"></asp:Label>
     <br />
     <br />
     <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="CommentsID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
          Style="top: 433px; left: -56px">
          <AlternatingItemTemplate>
               <tr style="background-color: #FFF8DC;">
                    <td>
                         <asp:Label ID="CommentsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Comments") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <asp:Button ID="DeleteComment_Btn" runat="server" Text="מחק" CommandName="Delete" />
                         <asp:Button ID="IgnoreComment_Btn" runat="server" Text="התעלם" CommandName="Update" />
                    </td>
               </tr>
          </AlternatingItemTemplate>
          <EditItemTemplate>
               <tr style="background-color: #008A8C; color: #FFFFFF;">
                    <td>
                         <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                         <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="CommentsTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Comments") %>' />
                    </td>
               </tr>
          </EditItemTemplate>
          <EmptyDataTemplate>
               <table id="Table1" runat="server" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border-collapse: collapse;
                    border-color: #999999; border-style: none; border-width: 1px;">
                    <tr>
                         <td>
                              אין ספאם
                         </td>
                    </tr>
               </table>
          </EmptyDataTemplate>
          <InsertItemTemplate>
               <tr style="">
                    <td>
                         <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                         <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="CommentsTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Comments") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         &nbsp;
                    </td>
               </tr>
          </InsertItemTemplate>
          <ItemTemplate>
               <tr style="background-color: #DCDCDC; color: #000000;">
                    <td>
                         <asp:Label ID="CommentsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Comments") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <asp:Button ID="DeleteComment_Btn" runat="server" Text="מחק" CommandName="Delete" />
                         <asp:Button ID="IgnoreComment_Btn" runat="server" Text="התעלם" CommandName="Update" />
                    </td>
               </tr>
          </ItemTemplate>
          <LayoutTemplate>
               <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px">
                    <table id="Table2" runat="server">
                         <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                              <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                                   <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="1" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;
                                        border-collapse: collapse; border-color: #999999; border-style: none; border-width: 1px;
                                        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                                        <tr id="Tr2" runat="server" style="background-color: #DCDCDC; color: #000000;">
                                             <th id="Th1" runat="server">
                                                  Comments
                                             </th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                        </tr>
                                   </table>
                              </td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr id="Tr3" runat="server">
                              <td id="Td2" runat="server" style="text-align: center; background-color: #CCCCCC;
                                   font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000;">
                                   <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server">
                                        <Fields>
                                             <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowLastPageButton="True" />
                                        </Fields>
                                   </asp:DataPager>
                              </td>
                         </tr>
                    </table>
               </div>
          </LayoutTemplate>
          <SelectedItemTemplate>
               <tr style="background-color: #008A8C; font-weight: bold; color: #FFFFFF;">
                    <td>
                         <asp:Label ID="CommentsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Comments") %>' />
                    </td>
               </tr>
          </SelectedItemTemplate>
     </asp:ListView>
     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CP_AllQuestionsAnswered %>"
          DeleteCommand="ModeratorSpamDeleteComment" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure"
          SelectCommand="ModeratorSpamComments" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" UpdateCommand="ModeratorIgnoreSpamComment"
          UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
          <DeleteParameters>
               <asp:Parameter Name="CommentsID" Type="Int32" />
          </DeleteParameters>
          <UpdateParameters>
               <asp:Parameter Name="CommentsID" Type="Int32" />
          </UpdateParameters>
     </asp:SqlDataSource>
     <br />
     <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="הודעות ספאם של אשכולים"></asp:Label>
     <br />
     <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ThreadsID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"
          Style="z-index: 1; left: 452px; top: 753px; position: absolute; height: 381px;
          width: 221px">
          <AlternatingItemTemplate>
               <tr style="background-color: #FFF8DC;">
                    <td>
                         <asp:Label ID="ThreadTitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ThreadTitle") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <asp:Button ID="DeleteThread_Btn" runat="server" Text="מחק" CommandName="Delete" />
                         <asp:Button ID="IgnoreThread_Btn" runat="server" Text="התעלם" CommandName="Update" />
                    </td>
               </tr>
          </AlternatingItemTemplate>
          <EditItemTemplate>
               <tr style="background-color: #008A8C; color: #FFFFFF;">
                    <td>
                         <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                         <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="ThreadTitleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ThreadTitle") %>' />
                    </td>
               </tr>
          </EditItemTemplate>
          <EmptyDataTemplate>
               <table id="Table3" runat="server" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border-collapse: collapse;
                    border-color: #999999; border-style: none; border-width: 1px;">
                    <tr>
                         <td>
                              אין ספאם
                         </td>
                    </tr>
               </table>
          </EmptyDataTemplate>
          <InsertItemTemplate>
               <tr style="">
                    <td>
                         <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                         <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="ThreadTitleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ThreadTitle") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         &nbsp;
                    </td>
               </tr>
          </InsertItemTemplate>
          <ItemTemplate>
               <tr style="background-color: #DCDCDC; color: #000000;">
                    <td>
                         <asp:Label ID="ThreadTitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ThreadTitle") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <asp:Button ID="DeleteThread_Btn" runat="server" Text="מחק" CommandName="Delete" />
                         <asp:Button ID="IgnoreThread_Btn" runat="server" Text="התעלם" CommandName="Update" />
                    </td>
               </tr>
          </ItemTemplate>
          <LayoutTemplate>
               <table id="Table4" runat="server">
                    <tr id="Tr4" runat="server">
                         <td id="Td3" runat="server">
                              <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="1" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;
                                   border-collapse: collapse; border-color: #999999; border-style: none; border-width: 1px;
                                   font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                                   <tr id="Tr5" runat="server" style="background-color: #DCDCDC; color: #000000;">
                                        <th id="Th2" runat="server">
                                             ThreadTitle
                                        </th>
                                   </tr>
                                   <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                   </tr>
                              </table>
                         </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="Tr6" runat="server">
                         <td id="Td4" runat="server" style="text-align: center; background-color: #CCCCCC;
                              font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000;">
                              <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server">
                                   <Fields>
                                        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowLastPageButton="True" />
                                   </Fields>
                              </asp:DataPager>
                         </td>
                    </tr>
               </table>
          </LayoutTemplate>
          <SelectedItemTemplate>
               <tr style="background-color: #008A8C; font-weight: bold; color: #FFFFFF;">
                    <td>
                         <asp:Label ID="ThreadTitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ThreadTitle") %>' />
                    </td>
               </tr>
          </SelectedItemTemplate>
     </asp:ListView>
     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CP_AllQuestionsAnswered %>"
          DeleteCommand="ModeratorSpamDeleteThread" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure"
          SelectCommand="ModeratorSpamThread" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" UpdateCommand="ModeratorSpamIgnoreThread"
          UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
          <DeleteParameters>
               <asp:Parameter Name="ThreadsID" Type="Int32" />
          </DeleteParameters>
          <UpdateParameters>
               <asp:Parameter Name="ThreadsID" Type="Int32" />
          </UpdateParameters>
     </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: two things wrong here `ASP` and using tables for layout!

Comment: Could you explain what you want to achieve more clear and provide brief sample?

Comment: It is an ordinary listView that i dragged to the design view...I havent added anything form my own

Comment: @alex please elaborate on what's wrong with using .NET

Comment: @Jason, nothing what so ever, its the cynic in me :) I stand by what I said about using tables for layout though.

Comment: @alex and i would agree with you about that!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your error is that you try to set Style on a ListView control directly. The listView control hasn't Style property. Actually there is element this style may be applied on. Move styles from ListViews to the first table in LayoutTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

Put the list view inside a div and give it a margin-left

```
 <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="CommentsID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
          Style="top: 433px; left: -56px">
          <AlternatingItemTemplate>
               <tr style="background-color: #FFF8DC;">
                    <td>
                         <asp:Label ID="CommentsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Comments") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <asp:Button ID="DeleteComment_Btn" runat="server" Text="מחק" CommandName="Delete" />
                         <asp:Button ID="IgnoreComment_Btn" runat="server" Text="התעלם" CommandName="Update" />
                    </td>
               </tr>
          </AlternatingItemTemplate>
          <EditItemTemplate>
               <tr style="background-color: #008A8C; color: #FFFFFF;">
                    <td>
                         <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                         <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="CommentsTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Comments") %>' />
                    </td>
               </tr>
          </EditItemTemplate>
          <EmptyDataTemplate>
               <table id="Table1" runat="server" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border-collapse: collapse;
                    border-color: #999999; border-style: none; border-width: 1px;">
                    <tr>
                         <td>
                              אין ספאם
                         </td>
                    </tr>
               </table>
          </EmptyDataTemplate>
          <InsertItemTemplate>
               <tr style="">
                    <td>
                         <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                         <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="CommentsTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Comments") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         &nbsp;
                    </td>
               </tr>
          </InsertItemTemplate>
          <ItemTemplate>
               <tr style="background-color: #DCDCDC; color: #000000;">
                    <td>
                         <asp:Label ID="CommentsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Comments") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <asp:Button ID="DeleteComment_Btn" runat="server" Text="מחק" CommandName="Delete" />
                         <asp:Button ID="IgnoreComment_Btn" runat="server" Text="התעלם" CommandName="Update" />
                    </td>
               </tr>
          </ItemTemplate>
          <LayoutTemplate>
               <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px">
                    <table id="Table2" runat="server">
                         <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                              <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                                   <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="1" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;
                                        border-collapse: collapse; border-color: #999999; border-style: none; border-width: 1px;
                                        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                                        <tr id="Tr2" runat="server" style="background-color: #DCDCDC; color: #000000;">
                                             <th id="Th1" runat="server">
                                                  Comments
                                             </th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                        </tr>
                                   </table>
                              </td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr id="Tr3" runat="server">
                              <td id="Td2" runat="server" style="text-align: center; background-color: #CCCCCC;
                                   font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000;">
                                   <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server">
                                        <Fields>
                                             <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowLastPageButton="True" />
                                        </Fields>
                                   </asp:DataPager>
                              </td>
                         </tr>
                    </table>
               </div>
          </LayoutTemplate>
          <SelectedItemTemplate>
               <tr style="background-color: #008A8C; font-weight: bold; color: #FFFFFF;">
                    <td>
                         <asp:Label ID="CommentsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Comments") %>' />
                    </td>
               </tr>
          </SelectedItemTemplate>
     </asp:ListView>
</div>
```